# CS50- pset3-tideman: lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs

Tags: c, recursion, cs50

Not able to figure out the test case, where this code is failing. All green except for this error: CS50- pset3-tideman: lock_pairs did not correctly lock all non-cyclical pairs. **I need to know the logical flaw here, more than the solution.**

// Lock pairs into the candidate graph in order, without creating cycles

```
void lock_pairs(void)
{
    // TODO
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i ++)
    {
        if(!is_circle(pairs[i].loser, pairs[i].winner))
        {
            locked[pairs[i].winner][pairs[i].loser] = true;
        }

    }
    return;
}

bool is_circle(int loser, int winner)
{
    if (loser == winner)
    {
        return true;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < pair_count; i ++)
    {
        if (locked[loser][i])
        {
            return is_circle(i, winner);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the recursive call of `is_circle` returns `false`, the function may not return immediately, but has to check possible other pair edges from the local `i`:

```
            return is_circle(i, winner);
```

has to be

```
            if (is_circle(i, winner)) return true;
```

Comment: Thanks, got where I was messing up!!